# TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input' when using TensorFlow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a model as the following code :

```
model_input = Input(shape=(449, 8, 1))
x = Conv2D(64, (25, 20),padding='same', input_shape=( 449, 8, 1),activation="relu")(model_input)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (25, 20),padding='same', input_shape=( 449, 8, 1),activation="relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(input=model_input ,output=x)
```

It worked perfectly when importing the following Keras library:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
```

But when I tried to use built in Keras API in  tensorflow and built the same model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

the error merged :

**TypeError: _init_subclassed_network() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input'**

I'm using tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 by the way.

Comment: I saw on Keras API, the params are `inputs` and `outputs`. Please recheck it, https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: It solved my problem!! But the weird thing is, I use `input` and `output` as arguments when library from pure keras API, it still works, but not working when library from tensorflow.

Comment: You can go ahead to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct and give you the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw on Keras API, the params are `inputs` and `outputs`.

Please recheck it, [Keras API](http://keras.io/models/model)